# The Data Type of All Values Has Been Converted to the Character After Replacing NA Value with "NA"

Tags: r

I want to convert the NA value of the data frame to "NA" (two characters). And I applied the following code:

```
df2[is.na(df2)]<-"NA"
```

However, this approach converts data types of all values to the character type.
Here is an example:

```
> sd<-c(1,2,3,NA)
> sd
[1]  1  2  3 NA
> sd[is.na(sd)]<-"NA"
> sd
[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "NA"
```

What I want is keeping the data type of non-NA values unchanged. Please help, thanks.

Comment: `NA` should not be quoted.  It then becomes a character string   Not clear why you want to do this.  The columns should be left as such instead of any changes to `"NA"`

Comment: When you change some elements in a vector to character, ALL elements in that vector must be of character type, since a vector can't have two different types. Why do you need `NA` to be `"NA"`? Maybe we can fix that problem another way.

Comment: @iod. Thanks for your answer. The reason why I'm doing this is that I'm using `if` statement to generate different outputs for different conditions. (e.g. check if two values are the same `if (df2$i > df2$h) {df2$h<-"smaller"} ) `However, if one value is `NA`, no matter what the other value is, it will return `NA` as the result.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the problem you described in your comment rather than the original question:

There's two ways you can go about this - either you precede your if statements with things like `if (is.na(df2$i))` and set a rule for what happens if there's an `NA`, or you can create a set of functions to replace the operators and know how to deal with NA in a way that makes sense to you. For example:

```
bigger_than<- function(x,y) {
  if (is.na(x)) return(FALSE)
  if (is.na(y)) return(TRUE)
  if (x>y) return(TRUE) else return(FALSE)
}
```

This will return TRUE if x is bigger than y OR if y is `NA`, and it will return FALSE if x is `NA` (or if both are NA, actually) or if x is not bigger than y. Of course, how you choose to deal with `NA`s could vary.

Then you can replace your `if` statements with things like `if (bigger_than(df$i, df$h)) df$h1<-"smaller"`.

BTW, note that once again, if you replace `df$h` with a character string (e.g., "smaller"), R will change that whole column's type to char - so you want to save those char strings somewhere else.